# Deploying SpringBoot Multi Module Maven Project in Azure

Tags: java, spring, azure, maven, deployment

I have a Maven project which have 3 modules. Three of them are SpringBoot projects. Three modules are Customer, Shop and Library. Here Customer and Shop module runs on different ports in same server and shares packages from Library module. The Library module has all the model classes, Repository classes and Service classes. Here is the project Structure Below,

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OiR0.png)

Now, I am unable to find any way to deploy this Spring project in Azure. How can I deploy this multi module spring project having different ports in same server in azure?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use ingress controller and services in azure to define your own ports[different] in same AKS container.
Assumption: It is assumed that you are using Azure Kubernetes Services[This details is not provided from your side ]